# Wordpress Plugin, capture comment insertion

Tags: wordpress, hook, comments

is there a hook to capture the moment a comment is inserted into a post?

In wordpress docs, they say that 'edit_post' works because the comment count on that post is updated, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an action hook called "wp_insert_comment" that's called from `wp_insert_comment()`.  It passes the comment id and the new comment as an object.  (wp-includes/comment.php on line 1245.)

Comment: hey, thanks. you are right about wp_insert_comment, but it only passes the commentId as an argument. do you know how i can use it to query for the whole object?

Comment: `add_action('wp_insert_comment', 'my_func', 10, 2)` the last parameter tells WP that you accept two args.

Comment: i did it using thr wpdb object, but i'm going to use your way, of course. can you please just tell me what the '10' means then? thank you, once again